# How to handle nil struct variable in struct type

Tags: go, struct

I need to marshal/unmarshal json to struct in golang. Assume the struct is

```
type A struct {
  Id string `json:"id"`
  Version string `json:"version"`
  Actors []actor `json:"actors`
  Payload struct {
     Name string `json:"name"`
     Number string `json:"number"`
  }
}
type payload struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Number string `json:"number"`
}
type actor struct {
    Id   string `json:"id"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
    Role string `json:"role"`
}
```

The actors or payload maybe empty. The json maybe

```
{
  "id": "78a07cea-be2b-499c-b82b-e4f510260484",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "actors": [
    {
      "id": "1234567",
      "type": "XXX",
      "role": "111"
    },
    {
      "id": "7654321",
      "type": "YYY",
      "role": "222"
    }
  ],
  "payload": ""
}
```

or

```
{
  "id": "78a07cea-be2b-499c-b82b-e4f510260484",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "actors": [],
  "payload": {
       "name": "XXXX",
       "number": "1234567"
   }
}
```

If i follow the struct A design and try to marshal json with payload empty, i have to init as below

```
a := A{
  Id: "78a07cea-be2b-499c-b82b-e4f510260484",
  Version: "1.0.0",
  Actors: []actor{
    actor{
      Id: "1234567",
      Type: "XXX",
      Role: "111",
    },
    actor{
      Id: "7654321",
      Type: "YYY",
      Role: "222",
    },
  },
  Payload: payload{},
}
```

Which will result in below json with one empty payload struct

```
{
  "id": "78a07cea-be2b-499c-b82b-e4f510260484",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "actors": [
    {
      "id": "1234567",
      "type": "XXX",
      "role": "111"
    },
    {
      "id": "7654321",
      "type": "YYY",
      "role": "222"
    }
  ],
  "payload": {
     "name":"",
     "number":""
   }
}
```

Is there any way i can generate

> "payload": ""

instead of blank payload struct? Or is there any other struct design for this kind of json format? BTW i cannot pass nil to Payload struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [json.Marshaler interface](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) can be implemented to customize JSON encoding, and the [json.Unmarshaler interface](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) for decoding (left as an exercise for the reader):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    Payload payload
}

type payload struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Number string `json:"number"`
}

func (p payload) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if p.Name == "" && p.Number == "" {
        return []byte(`""`), nil
    }

    type _payload payload // prevent recursion
    return json.Marshal(_payload(p))
}

func main() {
    var a A
    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(a, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(b))

    a.Payload.Name = "foo"
    b, _ = json.MarshalIndent(a, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

// Output:
// {
//   "Payload": ""
// }
// {
//   "Payload": {
//     "name": "foo",
//     "number": ""
//   }
// }
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/9jhSWnKTnTf

The ad-hoc `_payload` type is required to prevent recursion. If one would write `return json.Marshal(p)`, the json package would call `MarshalJSON` again, because p is of type `payload`, and `payload` implements json.Marshaler.

The `_payload` type has the same underlying type as `payload` but does *not* implement json.Marshaler (see [Type definitions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) for details), so it is encoded using the standard rules of the json package; it produces exactly the same output that encoding a value of type `payload` would produce if `payload` didn't implement json.Marshaler.

Comment: @Peter Can you explain
`type _payload payload // prevent recursion`
whats happening here or what should I read to learn about this ? :)

Comment: @Peter understood. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if using `omitempty` with json struct tag helps. I think it will result in `"payload": {}` instead of `"payload": ""`